# MATLAB - Correlation with Vectors

Tags: matlab, coordinates, distance, correlation, depth

I have two vectors XYZ with different sizes. We can call it Data1 and Data2, where:

```
Data1 = [1000 3:55 2000; ...
          950 2200 4.5; ...
         1050 2350 5.5; ...
         1025 2500 6; ...
         1075 2600 7; ...
         1000 2700 8];

Data2 = [1000 2650 7.95; ...
         1000 2750 8.16; ...
         1000 2700 9; ...
         1025 3000 10];
```

The minimum acceptable difference between the points is 100 meters to the position (X, Y) and 0.2 for the depth (Z).

In this case, the points between the vectors will be P_Data1 = [1000 2700 8] and P_Data2 = [1000 2650 7.95], because the distance is acceptable and the depth is the nearest.

Does anyone know a function that can do this correlation to help me? I think in Matalab there is some function to the problem and a high performance, for I will do this calculation for thousands of points.

I'm currently using a nested loop, but the performance is very bad, because I calculate all distances, then all the differences between the depths for every point and filter the matrix.

In short, I want to find the points with lower and lower depths between two vectors of different sizes to the defined ranges.

I thank you for all the help!

Comment: So you're looking for the nearest depth measurement that also fits the requirements in x and y?

Comment: There is a mistake in `Data1`. I think it should be `1000 3.55 2000;` rather than `3:55`.

Comment: ummm, kind of a silly question, but I don't think you need correlation for this. Based on what you said, you can simply subtract Data 1 from Data 2, which returns a matrix, take the absolute value of it (which is eq to taking absolute value of each element) and then filter through the condition that column 1 and 2 (referred to as X Y) has to be less than 200, and column 3 has to be less than 0.2, am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
Data1 = [950 2200 4.5; ...
         1050 2350 5.5; ...
         1025 2500 6; ...
         1075 2600 7; ...
         1000 2700 8];

Data2 = [1000 2650 7.95; ...
         1000 2750 8.16; ...
         1000 2700 9; ...
         1025 3000 10];

vec1 = Data1(:,3);
vec2 = Data2(:,3);
[p,q] = meshgrid(vec1, vec2);
output1 = 0; %initial set

while output1 == 0
sub = [abs(p(:)-q(:))];
[M,I] = min(sub);
IndData1 = floor(I/4);
IndData2 = mod(I,IndData1);

%this basically computes the smallest possible Z 
%Check if it works for condition 2:
checkcolumn1 = abs(Data1(IndData1,1) - Data2(IndData2,1));
checkcolumn2 = abs(Data1(IndData1,2) - Data2(IndData2,2));
if checkcolumn1 < 200 && checkcolumn2 <200
   output1 = Data1(IndData1,:);
   output2 = Data2(IndData2,:);
else
min(sub) = 1000000 %huge high number to basically remove the min
end
end
```

So this program should do what you ask, basically, it first calculates the minimum of the Z column, you can add a condition that it has to be less than 0.2 by the way, I just assumed that there has to be some value smaller than 0.2. Then it tries to see if the first condition can be fulfilled. Although it uses a loop for the search, it is actually very efficient, as it will jump out of the loop as soon as it finds the correct values.